# Windows phone emulator doesn't load images

Tags: html, windows-phone-7, cordova, image

um using PhoneGap to develop cross platform mobile app and here I'm trying testing my app on a windows phone emulator (um newly in developing on Win. phone)

I've wrote a normal HTML page has an element tag img

```
<img id="PlateImage" width="200px" height="100px"  src="Images\Plates\plate_blue.png"/>
```

I also tried to change path style

```
<img id="PlateImage" width="200px" height="100px"  src="/Images/Plates/plate_blue.png"/>
```

But no use my emulator display the *alt* attribute instead of the img itself.

any suggestions ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To fix this error follow these steps**

1. From Soulion Explorer, right click the image and click Properties
2. Select "**Build Action**", then select "**Content**"
3. Save and Run